# SharePoint Dataform and List view web part disappears from Site Pages

Tags: sharepoint-designer, data-view-web-part, xslt-list-view-web-part

I have Created Data Form web part in SharePoint Designer 2013 and it was working fine. But when i check out the page and check in again it disappears from the page.

Same happens with the List View web part also.

This happens very frequently when i edit the page in SharePoint designer.

Even after appending "?contents=1" to the URL i don't see my web part (refer following image).

[image]

Is there anything i need to consider while creating/editing the web part in SharePoint designer OR is it something wrong with my SharePoint Designer ?

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this issue?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: try uninstalling the designer and reinstalled it again. 
Also before SPD installation clear the files in here
%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Web Server Extensions\Cache 
%APPDATA%\Microsoft\SharePoint Designer\ProxyAssemblyCache 
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WebsiteCache

Comment: @bkk Thanks for your response. I have already re-installed the SharePoint designer hoping that would resolve my problem but it didn't work. Also i cleared SharePoint Designer cache but still same issue.

Comment: Have you tried using SPD from another machine, does it still give you same issue?

Comment: Let me try using SPD from another machine. I will let you know.

Comment: @bkk I tried using SPD from another machine but issue still persist. I got the error message on check in that says "We cannot do that for you because the file is no longer checked out or has been deleted" and after that web part disappeared from the page.  To resolved this i followed this link - https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/01/09/we-cant-do-that-for-you-because-the-file-is-no-loger-checked-out-or-has-been-deleted/ But it didn't work.

Comment: Review SharePoint Designer Settings under site collection settings. Ref. http://blog.ciaops.com/2013/06/disabling-sharepoint-designer-access-in.html?m=1. Check if the designer has been disabled.

Comment: I have checked SharePoint designer settings, and all the check boxes are checked.